# How to correct my web config connection string for remote shared server

Tags: asp.net, web-config, database-connection

I need help with my web config file and my connection string for an Access database. It worked fine on my local server but I cannot get the correct code for the remote shared Server path
in my web.config file and/or my web page.

I understand that I cannot use "Serve Map Path" in the config file so I have used a 2 part code (Web Config file and script in the head section of my "Webform1".  The database is in an App_Data folder off of the root.  The website pages are in a directory named "fsi"

My Code WebForm1:

```
<script>
    sub Page_Load
    dim dbconn
    dbconn=New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;
    data source=" & server.mappath(App_Data/"NewBase2.accdb"))
    dbconn.Open()
    end sub
 </script>
```

My Code in Web.Config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>

  <connectionStrings>

     <add name="ConnectionString1" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data
      Source=\App_Data\NewBase2.accdb" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />

  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

For this the error message is

```
c:\App_Data\NewBase2.accdb`' is not a valid path
```

I have tried several variations of the Data Source in the config file such as changing the Data Source to {0} resulting in the error message:
I have tried several variations of the Data Source in the config file such as changing the Data Source to {0} resulting in the error message

```
'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\{0}`
```

I have read all of the threads on this site related to this topic and have tried many suggestions but I am still getting error messages, primarily that path is invalid.
How should I code these two parts to get them to work correctly?

Thank-you to anyone who can help with this,
Psy51

Answer (score 0):

Trying removing the first / in the Source

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="ConnectionString1" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data
       Source=App_Data\NewBase2.accdb" providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
```

AFAIK \ will always return to the root of the drive hence why it's looking for c:\App_Data\NewBase2.accdb

Comment: Thank-you for the suggestion. When I remove the slash I still get error message. This time it is : [OleDbException (0x80004005): 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\App_Data\NewBase2.accdb' is not a valid path.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Connectionstrings.com?